# I tried scriptable object as an input reader from input actions script but it won't work for some reason

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, architecture

i'm trying to invoke input events from a scriptable object as a channel or a layer between the input action script and the player like what unity does in its open project "chop chop" but it is not working at all with no errors or warnings . i don't know why ? can u help me please ? (using the new input system) this is the code for the channel :

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using System;
 using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
 [CreateAssetMenu(fileName ="testScriptableObject", menuName ="game/test SO")]
 public class InputSOChannel : ScriptableObject
 {
     public event Action playerFire;
     private TestControls testControl;
     private void OnEnable() {
         testControl = new TestControls();
         testControl.test.fire.started += onfire;
     }
     private void onfire(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
     {
         playerFire?.Invoke();
         Debug.Log("the event invoked!");
     }
     private void OnDisable() {
         testControl.test.fire.started -= onfire;
     }
 }
```

and this for the player or input receiver :

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class ObjectController : MonoBehaviour
 {
     [SerializeField] InputSOChannel inputSOChannel;
     private void OnEnable() {
         inputSOChannel.playerFire += isfiring;
     }
     private void OnDisable() {
         inputSOChannel.playerFire -= isfiring;
     }
     private void isfiring()
     {
         Debug.Log("the event fired from the lowend!");
     }
 }
```

i really appreciate any help . thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i just forgot to enable the input action script , beginner's mistake